# floating element extends past footer

Tags: html, css

I am working on making a "school" type website which will have a secondary navigation contained within the "classroom" pages. I have the secondary navigation setup as an accordion which is contained within `<aside>` and `</aside>` tags. The aside element is set to a fixed position using the css `aside { position: absolute; height: 700px;}`. The issue that I am having is that my `<footer>` section is sitting in the middle of my `<aside>` section. I have tried using the css property of `clear: both;` for the footer section but this has no effect.

```
<body>
    <!-- Header section -->
    <div>
        <!-- this section contains a .php include() section -->
    </div>

    <!-- Main Body/Work space -->
    <section>
        <!-- this section currently contains holder text -->
    </section>

    <!-- Classroom navigation -->
    <aside>
        <!-- this section contains a .php include() section -->
    </aside>

    <!-- Footer section -->
    <div id="footerContain">
        <!-- this section contains a .php include() section -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The relevant css code is:

```
#footerContain {
    clear: both;
}
aside {
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 2% 2% 6% 0%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 7px;
    top: 165px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 900px;
}
section {
    margin-left: 23%;
}
```

here is a jsFidle example of what I am getting: https://jsfiddle.net/Dragoonman/1rx6dchc/

Any and all help figuring this one out would be great.

Comment: do you tried  using `position` for footer ?

Comment: @Kain: Yes, I just tried that and the only thing that it did was to move the footer in front of the aside tag.

Comment: can you make a JSfiddle example ?

Comment: The Aside top is 165 that makes it below every other div. Change this   Top:165px; or change aside from position: absolute; to position: relative;

Comment: @Harminder: all this does is drop my aside below my footer section

Comment: if you want to hide/show the text which goes after footer, either you can set scroll bar on aside `overflow-y: scroll` or you can avoid it by setting `overflow-y: hidden`

Comment: I believe you need to rethink what you are doing that requires absolute positioning for this to work. The elements you are having problems with are not problems at all but behaving exactly as they should and intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
}
.row {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}
aside {
 width: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
}
section {
 margin-left:20%;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: blue;
 vertical-align: top;
}
#footerContain {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <aside>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tempor ipsum in auctor commodo. Vestibulum non erat imperdiet mi malesuada interdum. In odio ante, luctus id eros non, vestibulum dictum ex. Mauris ac sagittis nisl. Maecenas non facilisis velit. Maecenas accumsan elit sed sem sagittis laoreet. Aenean eu luctus nisl. Praesent bibendum, dolor ut elementum posuere, lectus ex sagittis risus, nec lacinia est mauris ut magna. Nam vestibulum, mi nec tempor lacinia, libero odio euismod augue, et volutpat purus dui in quam.</p>
  </aside>
  <section>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tempor ipsum in auctor commodo. Vestibulum non erat imperdiet mi malesuada interdum. In odio ante, luctus id eros non, vestibulum dictum ex. Mauris ac sagittis nisl. Maecenas non facilisis velit. Maecenas accumsan elit sed sem sagittis laoreet. Aenean eu luctus nisl. Praesent bibendum, dolor ut elementum posuere, lectus ex sagittis risus, nec lacinia est mauris ut magna. Nam vestibulum, mi nec tempor lacinia, libero odio euismod augue, et volutpat purus dui in quam. Vestibulum aliquet dui at nulla volutpat, quis aliquam nulla viverra. Quisque in sapien sit amet tortor sagittis congue. Quisque magna odio, pharetra porta volutpat consequat, molestie sed lacus. Nam eget massa diam. Praesent accumsan ante nisl, in bibendum lorem ullamcorper a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer id magna ut purus maximus aliquam eget in quam.</p>
  </section>
 </div>

 <div id="footerContain"></div>
```

Whatever element is bigger, aside or section, pushes the footer down, so it can grow as needed.

Comment: That is similar to what I am trying to do except that the footer section (with an id of "footerContain") needs to be dynamic and have it's position be based on the height of the `<section>` area as this section's height will change based on amount of content within (and content will not be hidden).

Comment: @Dragonman86 I have edited the code to make a flexible display that pushes the footer as it grows. It's just one way to do it, hope you can work something from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#footerContain {
   position: absolute;
       bottom: 5px;
}
aside {
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 2% 2% 6% 0%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 7px;
    top: 165px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 900px;
}
section {
    margin-left: 23%;
}
</style>

<body>

     <div>
Main Div     
     <!-- this section contains a .php include() section -->
    </div>

    <!-- Main Body/Work space -->
    <section>
Section    
    <!-- this section currently contains holder text -->
    </section>

    <!-- Classroom navigation -->
    <aside>
Aside     
     <!-- this section contains a .php include() section -->
    </aside>

    <!-- Footer section -->
    <div id="footerContain">
Footer    
    <!-- this section contains a .php include() section -->
    </div>


 </body>
```

Comment: This brings footer at the bottom.

Comment: I just tried this using the full content of the page and all this does is move the footer to the left of the `<section>` tag and keeps it in the middle of the `<aside>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/adel_mehrban/zjn39mot/) for possible solutions:

1- You need to set a height which matches your section.

```
height: 350px;
```

2- Set the overflow on the aside (either to hidden or scroll)

```
 overflow-y: hidden;
```

2- set the right top for your asside

```
top: 20px;
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the only issue with this is that the aside contains an accordion list which is fairly long. Also at a latter time, the `<section>` area will be much longer than it currently is. I am just not sure of how to get the look that I need right now to in order to show my "client" what I had in mind for the site

Comment: in that case give both a height like 900px (although percentage is more preferred way) and put them both in a div with `overflow-y: scroll;`. This way you don't mess with aside or section but have the full content at all time

Answer (score 0):

You can use "clear: both" when you have floating elements. In this case, I recommend you setup min-height 100vh (which is the screen height) in the body and use position:absolute in the footer element.

```
body { min-height: 100vh; }
#footerContain {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

If you want full width footer:

```
#footerContain {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Reduce gap between aside and title.

   ```
   top: 20px;
   ```
2. Set height property of aside

   ```
   height: 100%;
   ```
3. Set overflow-y property of aside

   ```
   overflow-y: scroll;
   ```
4. increase section margin to accommodate scroll bar

   ```
   margin-left: 25%;
   ```

These edits put the footer under the aside and lets the user scroll through the aside no matter how long it gets. Hope this helps.
https://jsfiddle.net/1rx6dchc/4/